# Plural and Singular in Prashat VeHaya Im Shamoa

Tags: tefilla, words, shema

In the Parshat VeHa'ya Im Shamoa (the second Parshah of the Kriyat Shema), the verse begins with the plural:והיה אם שמוע תשמעו... ולמדתם אותם את בניכם And you put these words on your hearts and minds, etc., down to the words and you taught them to your children to speak them. Then the verse begins to speak in the singular: בשבתך בביתך ובלכתך בדרך ובשכבך וכו עד וכתבתם על מזוזות ביתך ובשעריך. when you sat in your house and when you walked on the road and when you lay down, etc. until you wrote on the mezuzahs of your house and on your gates. Why does the wording change from plural to singular and there is no uniformity between the verses?